# G-Reg and API manager Integration WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-cloud, wso2-governance-registry

Is it possible to use endpoints configured in G-Reg while creating an API in API manager?

Comment: Please elaborate more on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no straightforward way to do this. But it's already suggested as an [improvement](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4158).

But let me suggest a workaround. Here are steps in brief.

1. Store your endpoint in the registry.
2. Write a [custom sequence](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) to read endpoint from the registry, and set `To` header accordingly.

   - [These posts](http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/search?q=registry) might help on how to read the registry.
   - See [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+Mediation+Extensions#AddingMediationExtensions-Defaultmediationflow) for how to set `To` header.
3. Pick default endpoint as the endpoint type of your API.
4. Attach the custom sequence to your API.

That's it.